# Training of Siamese Network with Contrastive Loss Misses Parameter Updates

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I try to implement a rather simple siamese network and a contrastive loss function. I use a pre-trained VGG16 as a backbone model and strip away the last ReLU and MaxPooling from the encoder. Then I add an adaptive pooling and a plain linear layer to generate the embedding vector.

To test my implementation, I pass random inputs and check if every parameter gets an update.

**Problem:** As one can see in the output of my MWE, the elements 25 and 27 of the parameter list don’t receive updates. I think these are the biases of the last convolution layer and the linear layer. I also checked the content of `optimizer.param_groups[0][“params”][25].grad` and `optimizer.param_groups[0][“params”][27].grad`. The gradients are all zero... **Why is that?**

Additional: If one input is bigger than 224 by 224, for instance `input_1 = torch.randn(4, 3, 400, 224)`, the bias of the last convolutional gets updated.

**MWE using PyTorch 1.11.0:**

```
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Siamese_VGG16(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_elements_embedding_vector: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        encoder = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)

        layers = list(encoder.features.children())[:-2]

        encoder = torch.nn.Sequential(*layers)

        self.model = torch.nn.Module()
        self.model.add_module("encoder", encoder)

        global_pool = torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((7, 7))
        self.model.add_module("pool", global_pool)

        embedded_vector = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(25088, num_elements_embedding_vector),
        )

        self.model.add_module("embedding", embedded_vector)

    def forward_once(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        encoding = self.model.encoder(x)
        pool = self.model.pool(encoding)
        pool = pool.reshape(pool.shape[0], -1)

        return self.model.embedding(pool)

    def forward(self, input1: torch.Tensor, input2: torch.Tensor):

        output1 = self.forward_once(input1)
        output2 = self.forward_once(input2)

        return output1, output2


def contrastive_loss(embedding_vec_1, embedding_vec_2, label):
    negative_margin = 1.0

    euclidean_distance = F.pairwise_distance(
        embedding_vec_1, embedding_vec_2, keepdim=True
    )

    loss_contrastive = torch.mean(
        (1 - label).unsqueeze(1) * torch.pow(euclidean_distance, 2)
        + (label).unsqueeze(1)
        * torch.pow(torch.clamp(negative_margin - euclidean_distance, min=0.0), 2)
    )

    return loss_contrastive


model = Siamese_VGG16(128)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
    params=model.parameters(),
    lr=0.0005,
)

loss_func = contrastive_loss

parameters_pre = [t.detach().clone() for t in optimizer.param_groups[0]["params"]]

input_1 = torch.randn(4, 3, 224, 224)
input_2 = torch.randn(4, 3, 224, 224)
label = torch.tensor([1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=torch.long)

# forward pass
output_1, output_2 = model(input_1, input_2)
loss = loss_func(output_1, output_2, label)

# clear gradients
optimizer.zero_grad()
# backward pass
loss.backward()
# update parameters
optimizer.step()

parameters_post = [t.detach().clone() for t in optimizer.param_groups[0]["params"]]

idx = 0

for t_pre, t_post in zip(parameters_pre, parameters_post):
    if torch.equal(t_pre, t_post):
        print(f"{idx} : Equal")
    else:
        print(f"{idx} : Different")

    idx += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, in the contrastive loss, a difference between the two embedded vectors is calculated. During the backpropagation, the gradients for both inputs get accumulated. Because of the aforementioned difference in the loss, the accumulated gradient evaluates to zero. With some activation function after the last linear layer, we could omit this behavior.